# jakarta.xml.bind.MarshalException: unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, jakarta-migration

As we have request for file export for setting request we are try to migrate from javax to jakarta  code throwing Exception at jaxb.marshal using jakarta.xml.bind 3.0jar

```
public String exportSettings(final String reason) throws EpcisException {
        final File file = PathUtils.getTempFile(getServerPath(), "result_export_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".xml");

        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            final JAXBElement<Settings> settingsElement = new JAXBElement<>(SettingsNodeNames.SETINGS, Settings.class, export(reason));
            JAXB.marshal(settingsElement, os); //throwing exception at this line

            return file.getParentFile().getName() + "/" + file.getName();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new EpcisException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**ErrorLOG:**
jakarta.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "epcglobal.epcis.xsd._1.AttributeType" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation